# Como implementar o plugin Marker Cluster utilizando o Yagajs/leaflet

Tags: angular, typescript

Quero implementar o plugin [Marker Cluster](https://leafletjs.com/2012/08/20/guest-post-markerclusterer-0-1-released.html) no meu projeto que utiliza o [yagajs/Leaflet](https://github.com/yagajs/leaflet-ng2).

Na documentação do Marker Cluster, dizem que simplesmente preciso utilizar o seguinte código:

```
var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();

markers.addLayer(L.marker([175.3107, -37.7784]));
// add more markers here...

map.addLayer(markers);
```

Porém, no yagajs/leaflet não utilizamos o namespace L, muito menos o método addLayer, tudo é feito por diretivas, como no código abaixo:

```
<yaga-marker *ngFor="let alarm of allVehicles" [(lat)]="alarm.latitude" [(lng)]="alarm.longitude" [display]="alarm.display">
              <yaga-icon *ngIf="alarm.speed>5"
                [iconUrl]="'assets/truckk.png'"
                [iconSize]="[40,45]"
                [iconAnchor]="[23,44]"
                [popupAnchor]="[-5,-42]">
              </yaga-icon>
              <yaga-popup>{{ alarm.customer_child_name }} - {{ alarm.speed }} - {{ alarm.vehicle_plates }}</yaga-popup>
            </yaga-marker>
          </yaga-feature-group>
```

Como devo realizar esta implementação? Visando que na documentação do yagajs/leaflet eles oferecem o recurso de [providers](https://github.com/yagajs/leaflet-ng2#use-standard-leaflet-plugins) para tal. Mas eu não consegui compreende-los.

Comment: Provavelmente é possível fazer de ambas as formas. Mas de uma revisada nesse primeiro link, ele é da versão 0.1, a versão mais atual é a 1.3, pode ter mudado em novas versões

Comment: Pois bem, até da pra fazer seguindo a documentação do leaflet, utilizando o namespace L, mas isso não segue as boas práticas do Typescript, porque além de todo plugin redefinir o namespace L eu ainda perderei a tipagem do Typescript.... Preciso realmente achar uma forma seguindo o que estou fazendo, utilizando as directivas.